# Postgres Output not cosntant, Unix command

Tags: sql, postgresql, unix, psql, postgresql-9.3

Hello I'm using a unix command to execute an postgres psql script, which creates a DB, in theory it could be more complex, after this command i am using ">>" to save the  output on a file, the thing is it only save when the database succeeded on creation but when it fails because it already exists doesn't store anything.

Here's an example of the full command

```
sudo -u postgres psql -f /home/user/script.sql >> /home/user/output.txt
```

in the script i just have "create database db2;"

I'm Using Ubuntu 14.04 and Postgres 9.3.4

Any hint or help would be great. Or if any information needed i will gladly answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect `stderr` also, in which case there should be some error output from that case where the db already exists in the text file.

> sudo -u postgres psql -f /home/user/script.sql >>
>   /home/user/output.txt 2>&1

You could also wrap the command in a `bash` script which checks for DB existence first before running the command.

In general when running just about any command where you're outputting to a file, you'll either want to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` or redirect `stderr` to a separate file (depending on how you want to consume any error output). Keep in mind that some programs (`psql`, `pg_dump`, etc. included), will sometimes log **warning** and **info** messages to stderr, so the mere presence of `stderr` output doesn't always mean that there was a problem per se.

Comment: Thank you, that worked I refused to make a bash script so i could keep it simple for the use it has.

Comment: It's more convenient to use ` >& output.txt` by the way. Redirects both stdout and stderr.